# Does sys.path.append() not work on a Mac?

Tags: python, macos, path, operating-system, sys

I have used this code on my PC and it works no problem and gives me access to all the source code inside the ibapi library: import sys --
sys.path.append("C:\TWS API\This PC\Downloads\source\pythonclient\ibapi")

from ibapi.client import EClient

But when I run the mirror image on a Mac,
sys.path.append('/Users/paulbeasley/Downloads/twsapi_macunix/IBJts/source/pythonclient/ibapi')

it throws me an error saying -- ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ibapi'.

I am now pretty sure that sys.path.append is a PC only function. How can I translate it so it works on a Mac?

Instead of using sys, I opted to try to use the os library to append the path name instead using this code :

```
import os

pathname = '/Users/paulbeasley/Downloads/twsapi_macunix/IBJts/source/pythonclient/ibapi'

# Get the current PATH environment variable
current_path = os.environ.get('PATH')

# Append the new pathname to the current PATH
new_path = current_path + ':' + pathname

# Set the new PATH environment variable
os.environ['PATH'] = new_path

print(new_path)
```

It does print my pathname in the list of pathnames, but still throws me the same error when I try to run the script. How can I resolve my issue so I can access all the source code in the ibapi library that I downloaded to my computer? Thanks

Comment: (1) Format the code snippets correctly. (2) Did you add the Windows path `C:\...` to "sys.path" on a Mac?

Comment: when I tried sys.path.append on the Mac it looked like this -- sys.path.append(''/Users/paulbeasley/Downloads/twsapi_macunix/IBJts/source/pythonclient/ibapi'') and it basically seemed like it did nothing. I got the error -- from ibapi.client import Eclient
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ibapi'

Comment: I'm guessing the problem is that "C:" doesn't exist on a Mac.

Comment: I edited the question to reflect I am not trying to use 'C:' on the Mac

Comment: Why do you think `sys.path.append` is a Windows only function? What error do you get when you use it? And what was the value of `sys.path` afterwards?

Comment: `sys.path` has nothing to do with `PATH`. (The former should probably be named `sys.pythonpath` to make it more obviously linked to `PYTHONPATH`.)

Comment: P.S. modifying os.environ won't help, because it's used when Python starts and changes won't be detected.